# Wondering what "v" is, in SJCL Library encryption output

Tags: cryptography, javascript

```
SureSure = sjcl.encrypt("password", GetUserInputSTUFF, {
    adata: "{4687f36d-99d4-4223-ae53-46041297bef5}sbDU9DHzf0v3doe7aouZjEbW92750001489303Ktqr"
});
```

Output:

```
{"iv":"a6J6pjHFos2HOIghbEkGLw==","v":1,"iter":50000,"ks":256, //.... }
```

What is `"v"` and would changing it affect the security?

In one of their introductory pages, [SJCL](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/wiki/Getting-Started) do not mention it, nor have I been able to find info concerning it elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the [source code](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/blob/1.0.6/core/convenience.js), it's a version number of the ciphertext, but the value `v` is never set or used. Also, it is not documented, so this is pure speculation.

Normally, a version number is not required, because checking which fields are set should be enough to determine the format of the ciphertext. Since the ciphertext format of SJCL is stable, the version number was never changed and it doesn't lead to any special code depending on the version number.

Comment: Too funny! I just found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364434/problems-with-sjcl-cannot-read-property-replace-of-undefined and, since I had found a couple other resources that pointed the same direction, I will leave it for now.

Comment: Wow, that was long ago.